# How to set the outline of the elements on tab only and not on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing some tasks for accessibility(ADA) and the team asked me to set a visual pointer on tab only and not on click.

[image]

Right now I may see the light-blue outline when I click on the anchors and also when I tab over them. 
I need that outline to appear only on tab.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" spend more time researching accessibility and understanding how focus works. Clicking on a focusable element focuses it. Tabbing also changes focus. Don't remove focus indicators for click, fix the focus indicators to be more attractive while still accessible.

Comment: @zzzzBov I assume OP understands how focus works. You're denying problem, not providing solutions.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, to me, the question clearly is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153542). As far as "not providing solutions" you're right, which is why I left a comment. If *you* would like to provide a solution, you can absolutely feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: @zzzzBov actually it is not a matter of researching which I did already and in every I've found they say that don't remove outline for accessibility reasons and that's ok, but the QA on-site is asking me to don't show the outline when I click on the anchors, only when I tab over them. And yes, my question deserves a suggestion. Sure, I know how focus works, but my case is explicit. I already did the research, it is implicit, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question here, mate.

Comment: If you show a minimal code sample (which you should know by now is required) we might be able to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove outline on `click` event, and set outline on `focus` event.

```js
var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a"));

elements.forEach(a => a.addEventListener("click", function() {
  a.classList.add("no-outline");
}));

elements.forEach(a => a.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  a.classList.remove("no-outline");
}));
```

```css
.no-outline {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
Some text. <a href="#">This is link</a>.
Also we have <a href="#">another link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this will handle both clicks or tabkey events. They display differently, but then both call the same function. Hope it helps!

```js
/*********
 * function that simply toggles the pane.
 *  doesn't care what calls it, simply that
 *  it gets the proper data. We can call it
 *  in the click handler (as in the HTML) or
 *  in the keyup handler (as below).
 *  either has the same functionality, but
 *  can have their own processing.
 *********/
openCity = function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

/********
 * Handler for the tab key functionality.
 *  Processes separately from the click
 *  function, as is shown by the different
 *  coloring. However, either click or tab
 *  key can trigger the same tab display
 *  function.
 *********/

var tabIndex;
var tabEls = $(".tab button");
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("keyup", function(evt) {
    // Prevent the tab key from propagating
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    // tab has been pressed
    if (evt.which == 9) {
      // Currently, no tab has been chosen, so we select the first
      if ($(".tabbedActive").length == 0) {
        tabEls.eq(0).addClass("tabbedActive");
      } else {
        // we have a selected tab. So we either choose the next, or
        //  the first if we need to rotate through.
        tabIndex = tabEls.parent().find('.tabbedActive').index();

        // Remove the class from all tab els
        tabEls.removeClass('tabbedActive');
        if (tabIndex == tabEls.length - 1) {
          tabEls.eq(0).addClass("tabbedActive");
        } else {
          tabEls.eq(tabIndex + 1).addClass("tabbedActive");
        }
      }
      
      // Now that we have a selected tab, use that to toggle the pane
      openCity(evt, tabEls.parent().find('.tabbedActive').text() )

    }
  })
});
```

```css
a
/* Style the tab */

div.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

div.tab button {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

div.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

div.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabbedActive {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: #cc0;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```